# Random variable cdf

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X\sim N(1,2)$ and let the random variable $Y$ be defined with $\frac 1 X$. Find $F_Y(5)$ and $F_Y(-5)$.

My solution so far:
\begin{align}
P(Y<y) & =P\left(\frac 1 X < y\right) = P \left(X>\frac 1 y \right) = 1-P\left(X < \frac 1 y \right) \\[10pt]
& =1-F_X \left( \frac 1 y \right) = 1-\int_{-\infty}^{1/y} \frac 1 {2\sqrt{2}\pi} e^{-(t-1^2)/4} \, dt = \cdots
\end{align}
Am I doing this right or completely wrong ?

Comment: Suppose $y>0$. Since $X$ can be negative, it is not true that "$\frac1X<y$" is equivalent to  "$X>\frac1y$". Instead, it is equivalent to "either $X>\frac1y$ or $X<0$" (we may ignore the possibility $X=0$). You may have to handle $y<0$ separately as well.

Comment: @MPW so I will have two cases? Is the solution good so far or there something else i have to do?

Comment: I'm just saying that your second "$=$" is false. So you should probably reconsider what you do at that point.

Comment: @LexByte why you started to integrate ... you know that $X\sim N(1,2)$. So you can use $\Phi$

Answer (score 1):

The event $\dfrac 1 X \le y$ would be the same as $X\ge \dfrac 1 y$ if $\Pr(X>0)=1$, but here you have a random variable that can be either positive or negative.

If $y>0$ then $\dfrac 1 X\le y$ is equivalent to $\left[ X\ge \dfrac 1 y \text{ or } X<0 \right].$ The probabilities of the two events that have "or" between them must be added. Thus
$$
\text{If } y>0 \text{ then } F_Y(y) = 1-F_X(1/y) + F_X(0).
$$
And if $y<0$ then $\dfrac 1 X \le y$ is the same as $\left[ X\ge \dfrac 1 y \text{ and } X<0 \right].$ This time you have "and" rather than "or". So
$$
\text{If } y<0 \text{ then } F_Y(y) = F_X(0) - F_X(1/y). 
$$

Answer (score 0):

When $y<0$, $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X\geq 1/y,X<0)+P(X\geq 1/y,X>0)\\
             =P(1/y\leq X<0)=F_X(0)-F_X(1/y)$$

When $y>0$. $$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X\geq 1/y,X<0)+P(X\geq 1/y,X>0)\\
              =1-P(X<1/y,X>0)=1-F_X(1/y)+F_X(0)$$

Note that $F_X(x)=P(X\leq x)=\Phi\Big(\dfrac{x-1}{\sqrt{2}}\Big)$

$\Phi(x)$ is cdf $N(0,1)$. So $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$.

Comment: There is an error here. If $y>0$ then the event $\dfrac 1 X\le y$ is the same as $X\ge\dfrac 1 y \text{ or } X<0.$ If $y<0$ then the event $\dfrac 1 X \le y$ is the same as $\frac 1 y \le X < 0.$ You need to distinguish between positive and negative and treat cases separately.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I just edited!